# CSS table columns

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to make 3 responsive columns with a divider between each one. As the divider cannot be the whole height of the DIV, I have used tables to get the desired effect.

Now, the columns look just how I need them in a large resolution, however, as soon as you start scaling the browser down, the column sizes don't keep the same. They are not equal widths as I had intended.

Now usually, I would not mix px and % in widths, however, as I wanted a responsive website but also have the column divider 2px at all time - I have mixed them, I believe this might be my problem.

I have tried floating the columns, but I couldnt get the border as I wanted. I really am out of ideas.

Does anyone know a resolution, or a cleaner method to achieve this affect? The URL link is [here.](http://dev.charlyanderson.co.uk/TomMaryniak/)

```
.homepage-section-two{
    text-align: center;
    display:table;
    padding:0px 20px;
    margin-bottom:80px;}

.homepage-section-two-column-one{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 33.333%;
    margin-left:-25px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;}

.homepage-section-two-column-two{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 33.333%;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;}

.homepage-section-two-column-three{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 33.333%;
    margin-right:-25px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;}

.homepage-section-two .vertical-divider{
    border-top: 280px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 0;}
```

Comment: I personally use flexbox for this sort of thing.

Comment: I discovered it was the H1 titles that were the problem - they were too big and pushing the columns out.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use flex-box for this. However it does have some compatibility requirements take a look at [this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) link for more information on that.

Moving swiftly on, here's my proposal:

```css
div{
  display:flex;
  border-top: 3px solid black;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}
img{
  flex:1;
  height:450px;
}
img:nth-of-type(2){
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://dev.charlyanderson.co.uk/TomMaryniak/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/home-one.jpg">
  <img src="http://dev.charlyanderson.co.uk/TomMaryniak/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/home-two.jpg">
  <img src="http://dev.charlyanderson.co.uk/TomMaryniak/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/home-three.jpg">
</div>
```